# Linux Desktop as root : /etc/rc.d/rc.local refuses to honor "sleep 10" command

Tags: linux, terminal, desktop, startup, rc

adding this line

```
 gnome-terminal -e "gedit test.txt"
```

to the `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` works fine.

but can not get it to sleep 10 seconds before executing that command.

tried

```
sleep 10
gnome-terminal -e "gedit test.txt"
```

did not work.

tried :

```
gnome-terminal -e "sleep 10 && gedit test.txt"
```

did not work.

**UPDATE**

it looks like the problem might be..

```
/etc/rc.d/rc.local
```

is actually executing the commands before the desktop fully loads.

i tried increasing "sleep" to "sleep 120" and i noticed the desktop would not load for 120 seconds.

Comment: So you're saying the terminal pops up fine from rc.local, but the sleep doesn't happen?

Comment: very weird, now even that does not work. i am not sure what's going on here. all i know is `service NetworkManager start` working in there.

Comment: i actually increased the "sleep" to "120" seconds just to see what happens, and then i rebooted with `sleep 120` and then `touch /root/Desktop/test_sleep_3` what happened was, sleep is being executed before the desktop even starts, the desktop did not load until after 120 seconds passed.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Usually a DM/WM/Login manager only gets started after rc.local completed.